# Why does ES6 JavaScript run locally from VS and not from same browser after deployed to server

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have built a .NET Core application with VS2019.  In the application's JS files, I have used the `let` keyword in a few places.  Example `let x = 2` When debugging I have VS set to run the version of Chrome installed on my desktop (using file.js) and all works well.  Once I deploy the application to a server (and use file.min.js), the browser no longer recognizes the `let` keyword.

Any idea why using the same browser, it down grades to ES5 when deployed, yet runs ES6 correctly locally?

**Update**:
To recreate this issue use the Market Place extension [BundlerMinifier](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier)

When minifying the following code, variables of the same name are used in the transformation that leads to bugs in the JavaScript minimized file.

Within a .js file create an ajax call to retrieve some data.
upon success of data retrieval, loop through an array from within the returned value.

Use this language for the loop `for(let accts of data.accounts)`

**Current behavior**:
`for(let accts of data.accounts)` minimizes into `for(let t of t)`
Both the variable and the array property end up with the same name.

**Expected behavior**
`for(let accts of data.accounts)` minimizes into `for(let a of b)`
The variable and property should have different names

Comment: Please provide the complete source of the page (HTML) that you get in the browser when the error occurs.

Comment: seems like its a webpack issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer to my own question.

It seems a bug may be present in the code of the minimize plug in I am using.

I have created a bug issue in the GitHub repository that can be found here:
[Issue with minimize transforming to object to the same name #580](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/580)

In short, the true issue was not with the let keyword, but that the variable it was calling had the same name as another within the same scope.